# Bash: transform key-value lines to CSV format

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

<sup>**Editor's note:** I've clarified the problem definition, because I think the problem is an interesting one, and this question deserves to be reopened.</sup>

I've got a text file containing key-value lines in the following format - *note that the `#` lines below are only there to show repeating blocks and are NOT part of the input*:

```
Country:United Kingdom
Language:English
Capital city:London
#
Country:France
Language:French
Capital city:Paris
#
Country:Germany
Language:German
Capital city:Berlin
#
Country:Italy
Language:Italian
Capital city:Rome
#
Country:Russia
Language:Russian
Capital city:Moscow
```

Using shell commands and utilities, how can I transform such a file to CSV format, so it will look like this?

```
Country,Language,Capital city
United Kingdom,English,London
France,French,Paris
Germany,German,Berlin
Italy,Italian,Rome
Russia,Russian,Moscow
```

In other words:

- Make the key names the column names of the CSV header row.
- Make the values from each block a data row each.

[OP's original] Edit: My idea would be to separate the entries e.g. Country:France would become Country France, and then grep/sed the heading. However I have no idea how to move the headings from a single column to several separate ones.

Comment: Advice: show us some code.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Comment: Edit: My idea would be to separate the entries e.g. Country:France would become Country France, and then grep/sed the heading. However I have no idea how to move the headings from a single column to several separate ones without messing up the order of the entries on the list.

Comment: You want to use awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution with `cut`, `paste`, and `head` (assumes input file `file`, outputs to file `out.csv`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

{ cut -d':' -f1 file | head -n 3 | paste -d, - - -;
  cut -d':' -f2- file | paste -d, - - -; } >out.csv
```

- `cut -d':' -f1 file | head -n 3` creates the header line:

  - `cut -d':' -f1 file` extracts the first `:`-based field from each input line, and `head -n 3` stops after 3 lines, given that the headers repeat every 3 lines.
  - `paste -d, - - -` takes 3 input lines from stdin (one for each `-`) and combines them to a single, comma-separated output line (`-d,`)
- `cut -d':' -f2- file | paste -d, - - -` creates the data lines:

  - `cut -d':' -f2- file` extracts everything after the `:` from each input line.
  - As above, `paste` then combines 3 values to a single, comma-separated output line.

---

[agc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6136214/agc) points out in a comment that the column count (`3`) and the `paste` operands (`- - -`) are *hard-coded* above.

The following solution ***parameterizes* the column count** (set it via `n=...`):

```
{ n=3; pasteOperands=$(printf '%.s- ' $(seq $n)) 
  cut -d':' -f1 file | head -n $n | paste -d, $pasteOperands;
  cut -d':' -f2- file | paste -d, $pasteOperands; } >out.csv
```

- `printf '%.s- ' $(seq $n)` is a trick that produces a list of as many space-separated `-` chars. as there are columns (`$n`).

---

While the previous solution is now parameterized, it still assumes that the column count is known in advance; the following solution **dynamically determines the column count** (requires Bash 4+ due to use of `readarray`, but could be made to work with Bash 3.x):

```
# Determine the unique list of column headers and
# read them into a Bash array.
readarray -t columnHeaders < <(awk -F: 'seen[$1]++ { exit } { print $1 }' file)

# Output the header line.
(IFS=','; echo "${columnHeaders[*]}") >out.csv

# Append the data lines.
cut -d':' -f2- file | paste -d, $(printf '%.s- ' $(seq ${#columnHeaders[@]})) >>out.csv
```

- `awk -F: 'seen[$1]++ { exit } { print $1 }` outputs each input line's column name (the 1st `:`-separated field), remembers the column names in associative array `seen`, and stops at the first column name that is seen for the *second* time.
- `readarray -t columnHeaders` reads `awk`'s output line by line into array `columnHeaders`
- `(IFS=','; echo "${columnHeaders[*]}") >out.csv` prints the array elements using a space as the separator (specified via `$IFS`); note the use of a subshell (`(...)`) so as to localize the effect of modifying `$IFS`, which would otherwise have global effects.
- The `cut ...` pipeline uses the same approach as before, with the operands for `paste` being created based on the count of the elements of array `columnHeaders` (`${#columnHeaders[@]}`).

---

To wrap the above up in a **function** that outputs to stdout and **also works with Bash 3.x**:

```
toCsv() {

  local file=$1 columnHeaders

  # Determine the unique list of column headers and
  # read them into a Bash array.
  IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra columnHeaders < <(awk -F: 'seen[$1]++ { exit } { print $1 }' "$file")

  # Output the header line.
  (IFS=','; echo "${columnHeaders[*]}")

  # Append the data lines.
  cut -d':' -f2- "$file" | paste -d, $(printf '%.s- ' $(seq ${#columnHeaders[@]}))
}

# Sample invocation
toCsv file > out.csv
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Well done.

Comment: Not quite perfect, the hardcoded *3* in `head -n 3` assumes we know how many fields there are, as does `paste -d, - - -` which is used *twice*.

Comment: @agc: Please see my update.

Comment: That does do it all.

Comment: That's worked for me, thank you very much for such an elaborate answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/), `tr`, and `join`:

```
datamash -t ':' -s -g 1 collapse 2 < country.txt | tr ',' ':' |
datamash -t ':' transpose |
join -t ':' -a1 -o 1.2,1.3,1.1 - /dev/null | tr ':' ','
```

Output:

```
Country,Language,Capital city
United Kingdom,English,London
France,French,Paris
Germany,German,Berlin
Italy,Italian,Rome
Russia,Russian,Moscow
```

Answer (score 1):

My bash script for this would be :

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
echo "Country,Language,Capital city"
while read line
do
  (( count++ ))
  (( count -lt 3 )) && printf "%s,"  "${line##*:}"
  (( count -eq 3 )) && printf "%s\n"  "${line##*:}" && (( count = 0 ))
done<file
```

**Output**

```
Country,Language,Capital city
United Kingdom,English,London
France,French,Paris
Germany,German,Berlin
Italy,Italian,Rome
Russia,Russian,Moscow
```

**Edit**

Replaced `[ stuff ]` with `(( stuff ))` ie `test` with `double parenthesis` which is used for [arithmetic expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html).

Comment: A viable solution, but likely to be on the slow side for large input files, because  `bash` loops are inherently slow (especially so with calls to external utilities in each iteration, which, however, is _not_ the case here, because `printf` is a `bash` _builtin_).

Comment: @mklement0 : Thankyou. IIRC the `((..))` was originally a ksh feature which was ported to `bash 2.0`. Do other shells support this?

Comment: In addition to `ksh` and `bash`, `zsh` supports `(( ... ))` too; not sure about others.

Comment: Replace `read line` with `IFS=':' read line data`, and both *parameter expansions* of `"${line##*:}"` could be swapped out with `"$data"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a slightly more generalized version of a bash script that can take the number of repeating rows holding the data and produce output on that basis to avoid hardcoding the header values and handle additional fields. (you could also just scan the field names for the first repeat and set the repeat rows in that manner as well).

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i rc=0  ## record count
declare -i hc=0  ## header count
record=""
header=""

fn="${1:-/dev/stdin}"  ## filename as 1st arg (default: stdin)
repeat="${2:-3}"       ## number of repeating rows (default: 3)

while read -r line; do 
    record="$record,${line##*:}"
    ((hc == 0)) && header="$header,${line%%:*}"
    if ((rc < (repeat - 1))); then
        ((rc++))
    else 
        ((hc == 0)) && { printf "%s\n" "${header:1}"; hc=1; }
        printf "%s\n" "${record:1}"
        record=""
        rc=0 
    fi
done <"$fn"
```

There are any number of ways to approach the problem. You will have to experiment to find the most efficient for your data file size, etc. Whether you use a script, or a combination of shell tools, `cut`, `paste`, etc.. is to a large extent left to you.

**Output**

```
$ bash readcountry.sh country.txt
Country,Language,Capital city
United Kingdom,English,London
France,French,Paris
Germany,German,Berlin
Italy,Italian,Rome
Russia,Russian,Moscow
```

**Output with 4 Fields**

Example input file adding a `Population` field:

```
$ cat country2.txt
Country:United Kingdom
Language:English
Capital city:London
Population:20000000
<snip>
```

Output

```
$ bash readcountry.sh country2.txt 4
Country,Language,Capital city,Population
United Kingdom,English,London,20000000
France,French,Paris,10000000
Germany,German,Berlin,150000000
Italy,Italian,Rome,9830000
Russia,Russian,Moscow,622000000
```

Comment: This code nails the columns part of the problem, but requires the user to know the number of repeating rows (as *$2*).

Comment: Yes, that can be overcome as well simply by storing the line (or first part of the line in an array) and making a comparison. That is generally done in a separate loop that would precede the code above. I thought about it, but that would have clouded the direct answer.